# PHPUnit errors occur when running drupal-check

Tags: 8

I am trying to run `drupal-check` on the social_auth_dropbox module (`vendor/bin/drupal-check -ad web/modules/contrib/social_auth_dropbox`) and I'm facing this error:

```
Warning: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Matcher\InvokedRecorder' not found in /Users/Documents/sample/my_site_name_dir/web/core/tests/bootstrap.php on line 197
0/11 [░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░] 0%
Fatal error: Declaration of Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase::setUp() must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::setUp(): void in /Users/Documents/sample/my_site_name_dir/web/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/BrowserTestBase.php on line 39
```

Answer (score 3):

The first warning could make you think PHPUnit isn't installed, but since `drupal-check` is able to tell you that the declaration of `Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase::setUp()` is not compatible with the declaration of `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::setUp()`, that is not the case. If PHPUnit weren't installed, `drupal-check` would report more missing classes.

PHPUnit is installed, but it's version 9.0.0 or higher version, where:

- The [`PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Matcher\InvokedRecorder`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9.0.0/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/InvokedRecorder.php) class doesn't exist ([but it's defined in PHPUnit 8.0.0](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/8.0.0/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/InvokedRecorder.php))
- The [`PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::setUp()`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/8.0.0/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L408) method is defined as `setUp(): void`, while [PHPUnit 7 defines it as `setUp()`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/7.0.0/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L296) (The difference is enough to cause the fatal error.)

So, in short:

- The installed version of PHPUnit is at least 9
- The Drupal version you installed still requires PHPUnit 7

Notice that, so far, only [Drupal 9.x has been updated to PHPUnit 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/3113653), and in future [it will support PHPUnit 9](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3110543). Previous Drupal versions still need PHPUnit 7, and eventually they will be updated to support PHPUnit 8.

Answer (score 2):

I see similar behavior when I haven't installed PHPUnit and use `drupal-check` to perform the static code analysis on a module. The tests provided by Drupal modules/core require PHPUnit to be run, so when it's missing it seems logical `drupal-check` reports warnings/errors.

According to the documentation of [mglaman/drupal-check](https://github.com/mglaman/drupal-check) you should be able to exclude directories (e.g., */tests/*). However, when you are running this tool you might want to add PHPUnit to your development stack. One way to do this is to 
add [drupal/core-dev](https://github.com/drupal/core-dev) by running `composer require --dev drupal/core-dev`.

Another option is to use the contributed [Upgrade Status](https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status) module, which provides extra functionality on top of drupal-check.

Comment: As a side note, I've written a small article around using these kind of quality assurance tools: https://sicse.dev/blog/delivering-high-quality-understandable-and-future-proof-code